# how can i delete the figures- input-field after use

Tags: android, layout, input, android-edittext

the user can fill a field with figures. I use the inputType numeric decimal.
When the user touch the inputfield he get a little keyboard with the figures.

My Questions:

is it possible that the keyboard appears in that moment in them the app start? at the beginning without touching the screen? 
and
can i after the use the keyboard on the screen delete?
I hope you understand me.

Best regards
JochenI

Answer (score 0):

If I understud your question, you need the soft-keyboard to be opened automatically when activity starts. If that is the case, you can do it in few different ways:

#### Manifest-Based Solution

Open the manifest file, in the XML view. Find the activity which will show the keyboard automatically upon being shown.
Add the line `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"` to your XML.

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.ExampleActivity" 
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
/>
```

#### Code-Based Solution

You can also display soft-keyboard programatically from your java file using `InputMethodManager`:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
    Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(mEditText, 0);
```

Look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html) for more information about InputMethodManager.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: don't work. Do i need to change something in the Manifest or somewhere else?

Comment: Actually for code based you don't need to change manifest. But as I said, I didn't tested it so can you tell me what is exactly the problem with code based. If manifest-based solution works for you, you don't need code in that case.

Answer (score 0):

for show:

```
yourEdittext.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

for hide:

```
yourEdittext.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```